# Increasing the quota for an ECS instance in a region on Alibaba Cloud

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I am looking for a way to increase the quota for an EC2 instance on Alibaba Cloud for only a specific region.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that in order to do that one must have to open a Ticket with Alibaba Cloud, only then the quota can be increased.

To do that, click on the menu icon on the top right of the Alibaba Cloud Dashboard > Support > Open A Ticket.

[image]

Reference:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25412.htm?spm=a2c63.l28256.a3.60.6457745323IRoK

Answer (score 0):

it is divided into two situations.

1. normally, you could directly do the operations on the ECS control console.
2. some special region or instance, you would open a ticket to alibaba cloud guy, but sure it would 100% follow your request. you need provide the detail reasons.